# SQL - Find total number of orders made for each customer

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables `customer` and `orders`. Each customer can place multiple orders

- `customer` has a column `customer_num`
- `orders` has columns `order_num, customer_num`

I want the results to show like this:

[image]

Here is my current code which only returns all the distinct customer num

```
select distinct c.customer_num  
from customer c 
inner join orders o on o.CUSTOMER_NUM = c.customer_num
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below - using `count()` aggregation with `group by`

```
select c.customer_num,count(order_num) 
from customer c inner join orders o on  o.CUSTOMER_NUM = c.customer_num
group by c.customer_num
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are only interested in customers who actually ordered something, to get your desired result, you don't even need to involve table customer. Just:

```
SELECT customer_num, count(*) AS orders_made
FROM   orders
GROUP  BY customer_num
ORDER  BY customer_num;  -- seems like you want this order?
```

Comment: @Denise . . . Based on your data, it is a very reasonable assumption that any "customer" has at least one "order".  If so, this is the simplest solution.